# Insertar 2 registros en una tabla temporal y que solo cambie uno de ellos Sql Server

Tags: sql, insert

Inserte en una tabla temporal llamada #Temporal un registro, luego le hice un select y lo concatene ya que asi lo necesito, queda asi:

```
SELECT 
TipoInstitucion + '|' + CodigoInstitucion + '|' + FechaReporteDatos + '|' + Identidad + '|' + 
NumeroTransaccion + '|' + TipoParticipacion          
FROM #TEMPORAl
```

El resultado que me muestra es este:
`01|34|20210228|1808199400324|202102261202330628478808|1`

Lo que necesito es poder insertar otro registro exactamente igual pero con la diferencia de que el campo de final en ves de 1 diga 3, ósea el resultado que necesito es este:

`01|34|20210228|1808199400324|202102261202330628478808|1`

`01|34|20210228|1808199400324|202102261202330628478808|3`

El codigo que estoy utilizando para la insertar es este:

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATE  
DECLARE @FechaFinal DATE 
SET @FechaInicio = '2021-02-01'
SET @FechaFinal = '2021-02-28' 

SELECT

 '01'                    AS [TipoInstitucion]
,'34'                    AS [CodigoInstitucion]
,FORMAT(@FechaFinal, 'yyyyMMdd')                                                                   AS [FechaReporteDatos]
,COALESCE(c.TaxCode,co.IdentNum,SUBSTRING(co.IdentDocument, 0, CHARINDEX(';', co.IdentDocument)))  AS [Identidad]
,CONCAT(FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0', CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), bp.BPId))                                                  AS [NumeroTransaccion]
,'1'       AS [TipoParticipacion]
INTO #TEMPORAl
FROM dbo.BusinessProcesses            AS bp WITH(NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN dbo.BPClientsRelations      AS bpr WITH(NOLOCK) ON bpr.BPId = bp.BPId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Clients                 AS c ON c.ClientId = bpr.ClientId
LEFT JOIN dbo.OuterClients            AS co ON co.OuterClientId = bpr.OuterClientId

WHERE bp.BPId='628478808'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo alterando un poco tu consulta original, para incluir ambos tipos de una vez en el select, por ejemplo, creando una tabla *al vuelo* en el from.

La forma más sencilla de crear la tabla con solo 2 registros es con una cláusula `values` o con la unión de dos `select`s sin `from`:

```
select '1' as NombreCampo union all select '3'
```

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATE = '2021-02-01';
DECLARE @FechaFinal DATE = '2021-02-28';

SELECT   '01' AS [TipoInstitucion]
       , '34' AS [CodigoInstitucion]
       , FORMAT(@FechaFinal, 'yyyyMMdd') AS [FechaReporteDatos]
       , COALESCE(c.TaxCode,co.IdentNum,SUBSTRING(co.IdentDocument, 0, CHARINDEX(';', co.IdentDocument))) AS [Identidad]
       , CONCAT(FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0', CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), bp.BPId)) AS [NumeroTransaccion]
       , tp.TipoParticipacion
  INTO #TEMPORAl
  FROM dbo.BusinessProcesses AS bp 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.BPClientsRelations AS bpr ON bpr.BPId = bp.BPId
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Clients AS c ON c.ClientId = bpr.ClientId
       LEFT JOIN dbo.OuterClients AS co ON co.OuterClientId = bpr.OuterClientId
       cross join (values ('1'), ('3')) as tp(TipoParticipacion)
 WHERE bp.BPId='628478808'
```

O, como he dicho antes, puedes cambiar la tabla al vuelo por:

```
       cross join (select '1' TipoParticipacion union all select '3') as tp
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto